# List of Schur multipliers of small groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Is there any online resource or book that lists Schur multipliers for small groups? (where small means, for example, order less than 100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used GAP, with the following instructions for the group $G$

```
gap>   LoadPackage("HAP");
gap>   G:=Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(SmallGroup(k,h)));;
gap>   GroupHomology(G,2);
```

It gives the answer in the standard format for abelian groups "$[\dots ]$". 
 
For example for $G=C_3 \times C_3$, SmallGroup$(9,2)$, so $k=9, h=2$ we get the answer `[3]`
, as the Schur multiplier is $C_3$.

Comment: Nice! This helped me confirm that the quasisimple group $ SL(2,p) $ (for prime $ p \neq 2,3 $ ) has center of size 2 and is the Schur cover of $ PSL(2,p) $.

Answer (score 2):

The cas [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) can be used. It seems like D.F. Holt has a [package](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/D.F.Holt/) to calculate them.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't end up using that but your answer motivated a research that made me discover a way to compute them with GAP :)